# jQuery validation remove error message instead of display: none

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have the basic usage of jQuery validation:

```
<div class="form__group form__group--floating-labels">
     <label for="registrationFirstname">{{__('Name')}} *</label>
     <input type="text" name="first_name" class="input input--text fullwidth" id="registrationFirstname" required />
</div>
```

With the error placement:

```
errorElement: 'div',
errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                  $(error).addClass('registration__validation-error');

                     var placement = $(element).data('error');

                     if (placement) {
                         $(placement).append(error);
                     } else {
                         error.insertBefore($(element).parent('.form__group--floating-labels'));
                     }

                 }
```

It works the way that I submit the form, if it is has the error, the message shows up, I fill up the field and the error message gets `display:none`.

What I would need is - remove the `div` with the error message completely, not just hide it. Is it possible?

Comment: Take a look on the `success` or the `unhgihlight` functions, maybe it can help you (I haven't tried) - https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#success

Comment: @Programmer u saved the day! `unhlghlight` opt worked :)